# ReactiveCocoa error "Let 'value' is private and cannot be referenced from an '@inline(__always)' function" since Xcode 8.3 update

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I am using `ReactiveCocoa` for my iOS app, here are the two related lines of my Podfile:

```
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '5.0.0-alpha.3'
pod 'ReactiveObjC'
```

Since I updated Xcode to version 8.3, I can't compile my code anymore, the compiler throws these errors from `Pods/ReactiveSwift/Atomic.swift` file:

> Let 'value' is private and cannot be referenced from an '@inline(__always)' function

[image]

I tried to clean the project, and reinstall the pods (`pod install`) but I still got that issue.
Any idea about how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove private property at

`private let value: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>`

to

`let value: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>`

can resolve this issue

Comment: Yes I guess so, but I didn't want to modify the pod. Also, I found a solution (c.f. my answer below)

Comment: But in my case 
replacing pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '5.0.0-alpha.3' by pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 5.0.0' not working
. I used Xcode 8.3.1 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 5.0.0' Swift 3

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so replacing

`pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '5.0.0-alpha.3'`

by

`pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 5.0.0'`

in my `Podfile` and running a new `pod install` solved the problem.

**EDIT: looks like it doesn't work anymore so I'll accept Hieu Tran's workaround (be careful though, modifying a pod usually is a bad idea)**

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. Go to the root folder and just to remove .**xcworkspace**, **Podfile.lock** and **Pods** catalog. Then you need to run 'pod install' again in the Terminal. After that all will be ok! Enjoy ^_^